# Can anyone explain why what I am returning is not being picked up in later code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, nsstring, return

I am really new to Objective-C and this is my first question to the forum and I hope you can help!

I have a function in a class that returns an NSString, which in turn is used to change the text in a label I have on my UIView.

When I return something like @"This is a Test"; this works fine, but returning my NSString does not.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
NSString *result3;
if ([operation isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ ", openBracket, second, operation, first, closeBracket];
result3 = resultString;
}

return result3;
//NSLog(result3);
//return @"Hello";
```

If I return @"Hello" then this string gets passed through and the command later to change a label to this works. If I pass through result3 however nothing happens. I can do NSLog(result3) and it will return a valid string, it's just not passing through in the return result3 and this is what is really stumping me.

I hope I have explained this well enough and apologies for any lack of jargon!

Thanks everyone,

Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my machine now, but is it possible you have ARC on? You set result to `result3`, but then `result3` goes out of scope with the close brace. You don't need to declare `NSString*` result here, you can just write

```
result3 = [NSString stringWuthFirmat:...
```

Or even

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:...
```

Comment: once I am home and on my computer I will give this a go - thank you! I think I do have ARC on as I've received errors before saying that ARC explicitly forbids .... when trying to add retain or autorelease.

Comment: I can confirm that this works! I did the second line there return [NSString stringWithFormat... which solved the problem! Now the next time this issue comes up I know what to do - Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

+stringWithFormat only works of all parts of the string literal are not nil.  Else, it returns nil; just as you are seeing.  Check that every part of your string is not nil.

EDIT; I just noticed your syntax problems as well`*NSString *result3;` had better be a typo.  You cannot point to a class that's pointing to a var!  Also, you never explicitly instantiate `result3`, so you can't expect it to be non-nil.  Use this instead:

result3 = [NSString stringWithString: resultString];

Then try to return.

Comment: Hi CodaFi, thanks for the quick reply. I can confirm they are all non-nil, through an NSLog again this confirms it. Unless I am missing something but I don't think so!

Comment: Actually CodaFi there was a warning before saying 'Format string is not a string literal' does this mean something might be nil?

Comment: Hi - yeah it was a typo! That's edited now. With regards to your other suggestion I tried this but this didn't solve the problem unfortunately. When you say instantiating result3 do you mean with the @property(nonatomic, strong) command? I also tried this at the top of my .m file synthesising this afterwards. When trying to call result3 in my class however it wasn't recognised. Apologies for the beginner's jargon this is something I only started about a week ago!

Comment: No, instantiation is +alloc, -init, but in this case +stringWithString conveniently does that for us (that's why it and methods like it are called convenience methods).